# Creating ADTS frame on iPhone.... problem

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio, aac, adts

I am getting raw aac data from web stream and try to put it in ADTS frame in order to play it on iPhone.

It works for 10 seconds then sound stops and restart but seems accelerated or mixed with others audio data.

Quicktime and others audio app are unable to open my file.

It seems my ADTS header is  wrong but I am unable to find where.
Is there an ADTS guru there which could be help me ?

[Here my adts file](http://www.jesuswillsaverockstarstoo.com/show/page/number/1)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Thierry

PS : do you know a tool to check and report problem in audio file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found.

Frame size was not valid.

Also I found **afinfo** on os x which is very useful to get file info.